# How to load a specific UITabBarView from a UIButton in a different view?

Tags: ios, xcode, uitabbarcontroller

We are trying to programmatically load a specific UITabBarView within the UITabBarController that isn't the first UITabBarView. We have a UIViewController with a UIButton that should fire an action to load the  desired tab from the UITabBarController. Here is a screenshot of the storyboard showing a UIViewController that loads a UITabBarController: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the View Controller is loading the TabBarController with a segue, just override -prepareForSegue in the view controller, get a reference to the TabBarController using segue.destinationViewController and change the selectedIndex to switch views